# Why did the number of Nazis in the Bundestag increase significantly in 1953?

Tags: germany, nazism

Looking at the list of former [Nazi party members who were politically active after '45](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_ehemaliger_NSDAP-Mitglieder,_die_nach_Mai_1945_politisch_t%C3%A4tig_waren), we can see that there was a significant increase in '53 (from 17 to 45, so almost three times as many). That is the only drastic change, as after that, there is a slow but steady decline:

[image: image from wikipedia showing a graph of the number of former NSDAP member in the German Bundestag from 1949 to 1998]

What changed in '53 that the amount increased so significantly in that year? I assume that around that time a number of Nazis were released from prison, but I'm not sure that alone would account for the drastic change.

Comment: It's worth noting that 1953 was the first general election after 1949, so it's a natural time for large membership changes.

Comment: @cpast True, but there's still an unusual jump. One could eg expect a graph that starts high in '49 and then slowly declines. Or one where there are a lot more jumps at the 4 year mark (whenever the color in the graph changes). But neither is happening. It starts relatively low in '49, then jumps significantly in '53, and then has no more significant jumps in any of the other general elections.

Comment: @Philipp I'd argue that the (failed) denazification has a very significant impact on German politics today, and that the answer to this question might shine a light on some of that. I also think that historical questions, as long as they relate to politics, are on-topic on politics.SE (hence the `history` tag). I'm not that familiar with the policies of history.SE, but as long as the community considers it on-topic here, I'm fine with the move. But I think the question would be equally on-topic at politics.SE

Comment: What's the exact source for the numbers per year?

Comment: There are only two 4-year-periods without a change of the numbers - 1949-1952 and 1994-1997. The second 4-year-period might be correct, but i doubt the the first one is correct, too. If the numbers for 1949-1952 aren't correct, the question seems to be pointless.

Comment: @tohuwawohu The graphic is from wikipedia, I am unsure of their source. A frame-challenge answer pointing out that the numbers are entirely incorrect would be fine.

Comment: It turns out that graphic was [only added 3 days ago](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Liste_ehemaliger_NSDAP-Mitglieder,_die_nach_Mai_1945_politisch_t%C3%A4tig_waren&diff=217961445&oldid=215809079), so it might be worth [asking the author](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benutzer_Diskussion:U_rob_me), who doesn't seem to have listed their sources.

Comment: @IMSoP: Isn't it just a simple graphic representation of the chronological data contained in the large table from the same post ?

Comment: Fixed the title to call out the more accurate "West German". Its a technicality I know since both East and West Germany were "german", and West Germany was the direct predecessor to the state we today call "Germany", but I think the clarification is worth the 5 extra characters.

Comment: Might that be an effect of the age distribution in both NSDAP and the Bundestag?

Comment: @T.E.D. Not against the extra 5, but it does add a little redundancy, since if it's _'Bundestag'_, it _must_ be 'West'. On the other hand, what is "Bundestag"? To improve the title, I'd suggest replacing BT with 'parliament' or adding those letters for clarification? (NB: A title using _only_ parliament_ then does need 'West' ;)

Comment: The 1.616.953 votes that the **GB/BHE** received in the 1953 election, came mainly from (1950) 8 million displaced persons in western Germany. Since it was a clientele party, this should not come as a surprise.

Comment: Since many of the 27 elected persons were former NSDAP members, this would be an explanation for the numbers. Many of those moved in to other parties later, which would explain why there is no slump in 1957 when the **GB/BHE** no longer had any seats.

Comment: @LаngLаngС - I'd maintain that said redundancy was already there with "German Bundestag", but its not a bad point nonetheless. I'll tweak some more. I do like simplifying things...

Comment: Another thing not yet mentioned is that 8 years after the war it's quite likely that many of those with short sentences for crimes during the war were released from prison and free to vote who couldn't vote in the previous election cycle. Also, the first large batches of Germans held in the USSR after WW2 were starting to return around that time.

Answer (score 7):

*I edited this in response to the comments. You can check the history for the first answer.*

I consider this an anomaly in the first data point of the graphic. Note that the four bars represent *one* four-year term, changes within one term are due to deaths or resignations.

- **Germany had many Nazis in key positions after the World War.**
  This applies to both East and West Germany, but more in the West. Senior officials of the Nazi regime could continue their careers after the war, and it took half a century (when many were safely dead) before the German society took a closer look at their brown stains. For instance, many [senior judges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitler%27s_Justice) remained in their position. Similar in the government administration and the economy.
- **The [Wikipedia page](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_ehemaliger_NSDAP-Mitglieder,_die_nach_Mai_1945_politisch_t%C3%A4tig_waren) defines being a Nazi as party membership.**
  I have not checked every entry, but the list contains people who were [young adults](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Scheel#Early_life) when they joined the party, and others who were [17 years old](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horst_Ehmke) at the *fall* of the Third Reich. It omits [people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinrich_L%C3%BCbke) who were implicated for organizing concentration camp labor, yet did not join the Nazi party. To me the list is interesting reading but no suitable basis for statistical analysis without a case-by-case judgement. Quite a few claimed later that they were "forced" to join to maintain or start their careers under Nazi rule. Some of that are weak excuses, some are more credible.
  So I do not see the strong correlation between Nazi ideology and party membership which the OP assumes. Read about the [Gleichschaltung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gleichschaltung), the nazification of Germany after 1933, and the number of organizations **other than the party** implicated in the nazi ideology. Listing former [HJ members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitler_Youth) would yield even greater percentages.
- **German society was in upheaval in 1949**
  The question seems to assume that it would be *natural* to re-elect incumbents in 1953, and that therefore the increase in numbers signified a political change. [Denazification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denazification) was still ongoing when the first West German parliament was formed. Parties still required an Allied license in 1949. This ended in 1950, leading to the formation of more splinter parties.

Comment: Dug into it myself a bit, and this answer seems essentially correct. There was no real upsurge in support for right-wing nationalist politicians discernible in [the results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1953_West_German_federal_election#Results). It looks the the parties taking up that mantle came in 6th and 10th (and worse), which was only enough to net them 10 seats out of 242 (3%).

Comment: I don't know about this. I agree that the list is incomplete (as in, Nazis that weren't members of the Nazi party are excluded). But people who joined the Nazi party knew what they were doing. If we don't consider members of the Nazi party to be Nazis, who even is a Nazi anymore? And Walter Scheel was 25 (nearly 26) when Germany was defeated (23 when he joined the Nazi party). That was old enough to fly a German bomber, and that was old enough to know better (which is also why he lied about it after the defeat of Germany).

Comment: I'm also not sure if it's relevant that 10% of Germans were members. Of course all those people are guilty of holding up a criminal regime (a lot more Germans were). It's not like Hitler and a couple of guys were fighting ww2 and exterminating 6 million Jews by themselves. That was only possible with the support of the party, the military, and the public at large.

Comment: I did some quick math on the page linked in the question, and it looks like former members on that list were almost exactly as likely to join a right-wing nationalist party in the West German parliment as West German voters were to vote for one. Which is exactly what one would expect if there was no relation whatsoever between the two and we were just talking about random political figures.

Comment: *If we don't consider members of the Nazi party to be Nazis, who even is a Nazi anymore ?* - One of my foggy preschool memories from communism is my mother crying and talking with my father about the factory they were both working in trying to force its employees into becoming party members; if that puts a wrench into your enthusiasm, then so be it.

Comment: @tim, someone who joined the party at 17 could be characterized as a brainwashed kid. And someone who profited from the camps, yet did not join the party, could be characterized as an open-eyed nazi. So there **were** plenty of nazis and ex-nazis in German politics, but party membership is not a particularly helpful characteristic to sort them out. In recent years people looked at plenty of specific cases and found continuity in courts, government departments, and the economy.

Comment: @Lucian: ["Nobody was forced to join the NSDAP"](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/rhein-main/hessischer-landtag-niemand-war-zum-eintritt-in-die-nsdap-gezwungen-12807098.html). The party was actually [quite strict](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitglieder-Aufnahmesperre_der_NSDAP) about not wanting new admissions from 1933 on, though things seem to have [changed somewhat](https://www.deutschlandfunkkultur.de/nsdap-mitglied-wider-willen-100.html) towards the end of the war.

Comment: @Jan: Just a few days ago, I was watching a documentary on Viasat History, about a German man who enrolled in the war to earn a rare medal, thereby enabling his Jewish wife to be declared an honorary Aryan; doing this, however, entailed sending unarmed Slavs and Jews to their deaths. There were various underhanded or unofficial methods, embedded into the political system, of forcing various (categories of) people into various degrees of involvement, acceptance, or membership.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. The question doesn't really include the claim that all NSDAP members were complicit in war crimes. Can you, please, expand the last paragraph? Are you saying that these 28 new members were prevented from joining a parliament before 1953?

Comment: @Lucian I suspect the main character of your documentary may not have been very representative of NSDAP members and therefore not very relevant for this discussion. I would also caution against extrapolating from communist countries (or maybe, one communist country at a certain point in time) too much. E.g. most factories in Nazi Germany were not state-owned, which would reduce party influence somewhat.

Comment: @o.m. if google is correct, Globke also never was an NSDAP member.

Comment: @defaultlocale, the subject line uses the term *Nazi*, the body uses *Party Member*, and tim wrote that he sees the two interchangeably. If you read about [Gleichschaltung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gleichschaltung) or §4 of the [Gesetz zur Wiederherstellung des Berufsbeamtentums](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Gesetz_zur_Wiederherstellung_des_Berufsbeamtentums), you will see that it wasn't that easy in a totalitarian society. See also Lucian's comment. The graphic both over- and undercounts what I'd call genuine Nazis.

Comment: @o.m. Yes, but the core of the question is not about the definition of a genuine Nazi. We still have to explain why the number of NSDAP members jumped in 1953. If you think that some or all of those NSDAP members were innocent citizens who desperately wanted to resist the regime, but instead were forced to join the Nazi party, then I see your point, but that's the topic for a different discussion.

Comment: @defaultlocale You have to know that every german was a resistance member, or at best Mitläufer, with some of them hiding so successfully that the rest of the world was simply misled by titles such as Gauleiter… https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werner_Finck

Comment: The **GB/BHE**, which recieved the 27 seats (1.616.953 votes) was a clientele party that represented (or was founded to represent) the intrests of the 8 million displaced persons. So the claim that the main reason for voting for this party was '...to no longer be allowed to dominantly scream bollocks about 'master race' in public and some of them being indeed imprisoned, otherwise sanctioned' is deliberately misleading. [All-German Bloc/League of Expellees and Deprived of Rights - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-German_Bloc/League_of_Expellees_and_Deprived_of_Rights#Founding)

Comment: @Jan: They were not formally or officially state owned. Personally, I am somewhat disinclined to believe that there is any meaningful difference between Western and Eastern European authoritarian dictatorships.

Comment: Could you specify _which_ members were active after 45 that were 17 when joined in 44/45? _And which of those were elected in 53?_ (That young folks did not play much of a role in parliament in 53?) Without clarifying that, and lifting your comment about 'continuity' into the main body (there were inded much _more_ than the graphic displays back in political business, ideologically, funcionally, or as ex-party members), this A reads an awful lot as apologetic.

Comment: @LаngLаngС, I thought of Horst Ehmke and Rudi Arndt (MdL, not MdB), who were obviously not elected in 49 or 53. But their inclusion highlights what I wrote in the first paragraph: that there was a Nazi problem in postwar Germany, and that the categories of the list do not illustrate it. I'll add part of my comment to the main text.

Comment: OK. But is it perhaps your intention to highlight that in the Q we have a graphic, with an attached number, _and a list?_ It seems that the graphic and its number are not what you contest, but the much longer list given in the WP-link by QP, which then includes people active much later who were indeed young enough to 'join' the party in 44/5, still too young for the inquired 53 election, and then raise to much more prominence in late 50s and 60s to be included in that list?

Comment: @LаngLаngС, I want to highlight that the list and resulting graphic are using an unsuitable definition for showing the continuity of Nazi careers. One could make similar graphics about how many were in the Wehrmacht or the HJ, and would get equally unsuitable statistics. *I think there is no conclusion to be drawn from the jump between 49 and 53.* And the slow decline into the 90s looks like age-related turnover to me. Germany didn't clean house.

Comment: @defaultlocale "We still have to explain why the number of NSDAP members jumped in 1953." The omission of the word "former" significantly changes the meaning.

Comment: @Acccumulation It does :) But it's pretty obvious that all NSDAP members were former in 1953.

Answer (score 6):

Main reasons, within the frame of numbers given:

- with every day after Nuremberg trials, having been a nazi became less and less of a problem for filling prominent positions in West-German society and politics
- 1953 election became polarised in topics over East-West foreign policy and alliances, giving the staunchest anti-communists a certain edge
- most important: a new party entered parliament which favoured (ex?-)nazis even more than the other parties

The actual number given as "45" former party members on the Wikipedia page is not  reliable, but likely higher. For any given tim eperiod.

---

On a state level, the 1953 elections were the first elections for the West-Germans in which they could form their opinion not only on local performances, superficial sympathy and more important *promises* before an election. It was the first election in which the actual deeds in parliament on a federal level could be judged: past performances as a vague predictor for future actions.

Almost all parties in 1953 had 'their nazis' as members, with a very notable influence in the government parties of CDU, FDP. Chancellor Adenauer was known to justify this with 'if you don't have clean water, you use dirty …'. It was just too inconvenient at the time to let really prominent or 'top' nazis too much to the forefront of the public eye. Meaning that an all too prominent role as a leading figure for a nazi was now a bit more complicated. Behind the scenes, things were running smoothly again for former party members…

With one exception that is quite relevant here. The first election didn't know one party that really had all, the [All-German Bloc, League of Expellees and Deprived of Rights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-German_Bloc/League_of_Expellees_and_Deprived_of_Rights) (GB/BHE). The name already says 'those deprived of rights', this being an allusion to no longer be allowed to dominantly scream bollocks about 'master race' in public and some of them being indeed imprisoned, otherwise sanctioned.

The election in 1953 was predominantly about Adenauer's policy, mainly in foreign policy and thus about unquestioning Western course and allegiance for the West-German state. Which would mean 'sacrificing' unified Germany, eastern possessions etc. A pill quite hard to swallow for really many, who then had to look for other options, even if they were otherwise right-wing conservative, post-fascist in leaning: A more unification oriented Social-Democrat opposition was too left wing, to not even think of the communists who did strive for a unified communist Germany then.

Many found the GB/BHE the most attractive option. It had a not so secret name inviting former comrades back into power, promised even more than the governing conservatives to never let got of any eastern German territories, to rehabilitate 'the rights' of 'the right'. This party, founded in 1950, even had a chairman with the following features:

- participant in the Beer-Hall-Putsch (minor role as young student, but 4 days in prison as result)
- member of the NSDAP since 1933 (No: 2.331.552)
- member of the SA since 1933
- part of Gauleiter administration, responsible for Germanisation-policy in Poland, leader of "Arbeitsgemeinschaft zur Erforschung der bolschewistischen Weltgefahr im Einsatzstab Reichsleiter Rosenberg" (Working Group for the Study of the Bolshevik World Danger in the Operational Staff of Reichsleiter Rosenberg)
- organiser of a Putsch in 1934 in Memel area to turn that strip into Nazi territory
- a fierce proponent of ethnic cleansing in Poland, even more racist than many other nazis
- convicted 1960 in East-Berlin in absentia for war crimes and crimes against humanity as a participant in a death squadron in Ukraine

This list goes on. He had some internal trouble due to power struggle competition with the SS, but he was clearly a guilt-laden top-nazi. Regarded as *and respected* as a [*Mitläufer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitl%C3%A4ufer) in West-Germany.

This man, [Theodor Oberländer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodor_Oberl%C3%A4nder), was elected to parliament in 1953. Together with his party, quite full of not-so-hidden nazis, bolsteríng the  number of 'too many nazis still at helm'. But if that wasn't enough, his post-fascist nazi party joined Adenauer's government!

Oberländer became head of the [Federal Ministry of Displaced Persons, Refugees and War Victims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Ministry_of_Displaced_Persons,_Refugees_and_War_Victims) a position in which he could show off his 'expertise' on eastern affairs, and showcase the demands to reinstate Germany within the borders of 1937.

In order to verify this explanation for 'the big jump' in the numbers of former nazi party members now in parliament, on might also just count [BG/BHE members in the Wikipedia list](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_ehemaliger_NSDAP-Mitglieder,_die_nach_Mai_1945_politisch_t%C3%A4tig_waren), watching out for 'Bundestag' and '1953'. Perhaps even just comparing and following up on the info mostly available on [List of members of the West German Deutschen Bundestages (2. election period)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Mitglieder_des_Deutschen_Bundestages_(2._Wahlperiode)).

Note also that the [elections results:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1953_West_German_federal_election#Results) the more open fascist DRP lost all of their five seats, while the GB/BHE entered fresh with 27 seats from the start.

This 'trend' became quite visible when in 1950 the new GB/BHE entered for example the state parliament of Schleswig-Holstein: a genuine  member  of the antifascist resistance, [Paul Pagel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Pagel) was to be elected prime minister but was blocked by the second strongest party, the GB/BHE. That party campaigned most strongly on an 'end denazifaction' claim, but was only the loudest voice for that, with the other parties mainly agreeing on that.

Note that Wikipedia uses an election campaign poster from 1949 and the *FDP* to illustrate [the topic.](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlussstrichdebatte?wprov=srpw1_0) The GB/BHE was a little more traditional in visual aesthetics:

For the [1953 campaign:](https://www.hdg.de/lemo/bestand/objekt/plakat-gesamtdeutscher-block.html)
[image]

as [well as:](https://www.deutsche-digitale-bibliothek.de/item/2KKTQMNSDB7NOMZRLEPWOWC4TY6JXAV3)

[image]

For the [1957 campaign:](https://www.leo-bw.de/web/guest/detail/-/Detail/details/DOKUMENT/labw_findmittel_06/labw-1-808405/GB-BHE%20Bundestagswahl%201957)
[image]

With some arguing for a Germany within its 1937 borders, the GB/BHE still was most aggressively advertising [its/'the German' claim to Sudetenland:](https://brill.com/view/book/edcoll/9783657772667/B9783657772667-s030.xml)

[image]

Instead of Pagel, the nazi [Walter Bartram](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Bartram) (No 3.749.168, now CDU) became prime minister in 1950 Schleswig-Holstein. With Pagel as one of his ministers, then interior affairs. But since Pagel was *the only member* of that cabinet *without* a nazi past, he coined the term ["renazification"](https://geschichte-s-h.de/sh-von-a-bis-z/r/renazifizierung/) for the whole process. Almost needless to emphasise now, Bartram then went on to the federal parliament *Bundestag* for the CDU, from 1952 to 1957.

To repeat and emphasise what's perhaps only inferable from the above: the GB/BHE was *not* the only party delegating nazis into parliament and other places of power at that time. But the [Wikipedia entry summarises correctly:](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gesamtdeutscher_Block/Bund_der_Heimatvertriebenen_und_Entrechteten#Politik)

> The BHE played a central role in the termination of denazification and the professional reintegration of former National Socialists who had encountered career problems because of their past. It was a rallying point for anti-communist and revanchist forces in the young Federal Republic. Its ranks included many former NSDAP members, among them Kraft and Oberländer. Kraft therefore made a point of stating as early as 1952 that the BHE was the party "also of former Nazis, but not of those who are still Nazis today." […]
>
> Of the party's members, senior positions included many former members of the NSDAP, including convicted war criminals.

With the part about 'not of those who are still Nazis today' subject to definition issues and some fruitless debate about that. Kraft himself joined the SS in 1939, the NSDAP in 1943.

To drive it home: the first two parliamentary group leaders of GB/BHE after 1953 were:

- [Horst Haasler](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horst_Haasler), NSDAP since 37/38, later joined CDU
- [Karl Mocker](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Mocker), first [Sudeten German Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudeten_German_Party), then NSDAP, later GDP

The *Bundestag* itself remembers this period as '[Back on the World Stage'](https://www.bundestag.de/dokumente/textarchiv/23235558_wahlperioden02-199554). A less (prominently) accessible, yet official and not very flattering overview is found in Deutscher Bundestag Drucksache 17/8134 17. Wahlperiode 14. 12. 2011, "Antwort der Bundesregierung auf die Große Anfrage der Abgeordneten Jan Korte, Sevim Dagdelen, Ulla Jelpke, weiterer Abgeordneter und der Fraktion DIE LINKE. – Drucksache 17/4126 – Umgang mit der NS-Vergangenheit ([PDF](https://dserver.bundestag.de/btd/17/081/1708134.pdf)). It also highlights the even much bigger reintegration of nazi civil servants into their former positions, mainly under the [131 law](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gesetz_zur_Regelung_der_Rechtsverh%C3%A4ltnisse_der_unter_Artikel_131_des_Grundgesetzes_fallenden_Personen) of 1951.

A severely deficient but English language journalistic approach to that document:

> After World War II, West Germany rapidly made the transition from murderous dictatorship to model democracy. Or did it? New documents reveal just how many officials from the Nazi regime found new jobs in Bonn. A surprising number were chosen for senior government positions.
>
> — Ralf Beste et al: ["The Role Ex-Nazis Played in Early West Germany"](https://www.spiegel.de/international/germany/from-dictatorship-to-democracy-the-role-ex-nazis-played-in-early-west-germany-a-810207.html), Der Spiegel, 06.03.2012.

---

For a summary of the main topics and dynamics in that election:

— Mathias Friedel: "Bundestagswahl 1953" (p112), in: Nikolaus Jackob (ed): "Wahlkämpfe in Deutschland. Fallstudien zur Wahlkampfkommunikation 1912 – 2005", VS Verlag für Sozialwissenschaften: Wiesbaden, 2007.

A short 'tip of the iceberg' narrative summary of nazis in politics:

— Wolfgang Michal: ["Nazis im Bundestag"](https://www.wolfgangmichal.de/2017/09/20/nazis-im-bundestag/), 20. Sep 2017.

---

Important final caveat:

The Wikipedia page on [Liste ehemaliger NSDAP-Mitglieder, die nach Mai 1945 politisch tätig waren](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_ehemaliger_NSDAP-Mitglieder,_die_nach_Mai_1945_politisch_t%C3%A4tig_waren) is explicitly mentioned as unreliable in the following publication. For once, it is incomplete, therefore even just counting the 'known party members' and making a graph from that underestimates the extent. Second, a 'nazi' might be in the SS, the SA or otherwise involved in extermination and other policies, but not be a formal party member. Since the question is explicitly exclusively about 'former party members in parliament in 1953', a focus on that subgroup is still lackinga robust scholarly study of the problem:

> The National Socialist past of the members of the first to the fifth German Bundestag has not yet been systematically researched, nor has that of the Bundestag staff. There are only isolated preliminary studies on the National Socialist affiliations of members of the German Bundestag, which, however, are of limited significance in view of the total number of members of the Bundestag. […]
>
> The aforementioned gaps in the documentation of the life phases during the National Socialist era cannot be compensated for with the help of other works either. Neither — the online publication "M.d.B. Die Volksvertretung 1946-1972" published by the Commission for the History of Parliamentarism and Political Parties, which documents the curricula vitae of MPs in a similar way to the Biographical Handbook, nor the compilation "List of former NSDAP members who were politically active after May 1945" in Wikipedia — can lay claim to complete coverage of the relevant biographical features or NSDAP membership of members of the Bundestag, characterized by a consistent systematic approach.
>
> —  Wissenschaftliche Dienste de Bundestages: "Sachstand Zur Forschungslage bezüglich der nationalsozialistischen Vergangenheit von Bundestagsabgeordneten und Bundestagsmitarbeitern", Deutscher Bundestag WD 1 - 3000 – 045/18, 2018. ([PDF](https://www.bundestag.de/resource/blob/823830/94971e81723febd93a43282820bd6515/WD-1-045-18-pdf-data.pdf))

That means the explanations above only cover those former members most well known, not all of them. Some have succeeded to this day to hide their tracks.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting how Wikipedia translates Gesamtdeutscher Block as All-German Bloc (not to be confused with Alldeutscher Verband), but Gesamtdeutsche Mannschaft as United German team.

Comment: (-1) The foundation of the **GB/BHE** was the **Der Block der Heimatvertriebenen und Entrechteten** (The bloc of the displaced and disenfranchised), founded in 1950 in Schleswig-Holstein that had the highest proportion of its population that had been displaced and disenfranchised. The 1.616.953 votes that the **GB/BHE** received in the 1953 election, came mainly from (1950) 8 million displaced persons in western Germany. Since it was a clientele party, this should not come as a surprise. This one sided answer fails to mention this background at all.

Comment: "One-sided"? Yeah, sorry, those poor nazis were really treated unfairly, always, for a while back then. As a persecuting innocence they deserve all the more pity, now, on History:SE. The question asks about the jumping increase of PGs in parliament, and the answer is that many came with a BHE ticket. If anyone wants to argue that expelling Germans from the East causes traditional nazi candidates to come forward and winning votes in 1953, then that might be an 'interesting' answer in itself.

Comment: The fact that the **GB/BHE** only received 20% of the 8 million displaced persons, it should say a lot. But for you, based in your answer, its sole purpose is the resurrection of the NSDAP. You even provide the link that gives the answer to the OP question: *However, with their ongoing integration in the West German society of the Wirtschaftswunder era, more and more expellees saw no need for a parliamentary representation beside the BdV pressure-group, and the role of the party dwindled away.* All of this you deliberately leave out.

Comment: A _fun fact_ indeed for a Q about '53 election results' that expelled Germans were voting less for GB/BHE _after_ 1953, with their nazi members in parliament often just switching party allegiance (another more important cause for the party's demise), staying as MP, like Oberländer as minister until 1960, and in later elections with supporting votes still well above 5% in some state elections? What is misleading is that dreadful line from WP, overall, but thankfully, it doesn't apply the slightest in timeframe for this Q.

Comment: @LangLangC Actuality that is what this question is about ('Why did the number of Nazis in the West German Bundestag **increase significantly in 1953**?'). Of the 28 extra seats, 27 where from this party  was clientele party of the displaced and disenfranchised (what you re-term as  ''those deprived of rights', this being an allusion to no longer be allowed to dominantly scream bollocks about 'master race' in public and some of them being indeed imprisoned, otherwise sanctioned'), which your answer doesn't address at all.

Comment: @LаngLаngС, there was no corresponding drop when the GB/BHE failed to gain seats in 57. Which points to my answer about the signal-to-noise ratio of the benchmark that was used, which you also mention. Also, how do you rate the effects of being the second election vs. being the first election without Allied licensing of parties? Many good points and (+1) from me.

Comment: @o.m. First election was indeed more antifascist (compare development from post-war Ahlener program/CDU to Adenauer49). The 57 election was characterised by many BHE members switching tickets mid-term post53: mainly Kraft/Oberländer leading them into CDU ("KO-Gruppe"). They took big part of their constituency with em & CDU/CSU & FDP made an attractive conservative offer: claim at least one Germany now (like Hallsteindoktrin), maintain formal claim on the East (for later), and indeed integrate many refugees on fiction of clean vests, and 'don't mention the war' (or worse bits of the past).

Comment: Reading a lot of this is interesting, especially since I recalled the BHE being primarily a *Vertriebenenpartei* from back in school - but it would be no surprise that this aspect was swept under the rug!

Answer (score 2):

### End of WW2 era and denazification, start of Cold War era

It must be said that among vast majority of (Western) German population after the WW2, there was a general concusses it would be best to forget WW2, or at least least set it aside, and concentrate on present circumstances and attempts to improve them. Overall, electorate in first elections in [1949](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1949_West_German_federal_election) and [1953](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1953_West_German_federal_election) was mostly divided between Christian-democrats and social-democrats. Despite sometimes vast differences in economic politics (capitalism versus some kind of socialism), both of these major parties accepted that Germany is now part of Western world (parliamentary democracies) and tries to align themselves with its values, as opposed to one-party systems like it was in Third Reich, or is now in Soviet Union and satellites.

This goes especially for CDU/CSU which was part of ruling coalition at this time and gave chancellor ([Konrad Adenauer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konrad_Adenauer)). While social-democrats were sometimes flirting with idea of Germany being neutral between USA and USSR, Christian-democrats were staunchly pro-American and this resonated well with the voters. Adenauer was firmly dedicated to idea of integrating Germany into Atlantic structures (which would become NATO) and Western European structures (which would become EU) . His idea was that Germany is now becoming a member of a new coalition of states and hopefully player in a winning team. On the other hand, he and his government carefully skirted around WW2 topics, in principle admitting German defeat and guilt, but also demanding German unification (with East Germany ) and sometimes giving a hint that they would like return to German borders of 1937. This last idea was borderline controversial, as Germany was filled with those [expelled mostly from Eastern Europe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_and_expulsion_of_Germans_(1944%E2%80%931950)), but also goes somewhat contrary to decisions made by victorious countries after the war. In any case, Adenauer and his coalition were fighting for refugee/expellee vote, but were smart enough not to hint any kind of offensive war to achieve that. This in turn was well accepted by war weary German population.

Of course, German whishes were one thing, but decisions of WW2 victors were something else. Overall pattern was that countries more devastated by German aggression during the war tended to push for harsher punishment (vengeance), while those that avoided said devastation (US above others) relatively quickly moved from sanctioning to helping. Indeed, Americans in 1945 started with [JCS 1067](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morgenthau_Plan#JCS_1067) (light version of [Morgenthau "starvation" Plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morgenthau_Plan)), but already in [1948](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshall_Plan#West_Germany_and_Austria) Germany was included into Marshall Plan. Main [Nuremberg trials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuremberg_trials) ended in 1946, and [subsequent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequent_Nuremberg_trials) in 1948. There were war crimes trials after that, but to accused individuals and not certain groups within German state. Policy of [denazification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denazification#American_zone) (which prevented many former National-Socialist from participating in public life of Germany) met similar fate. While starting grandiosely in 1945-46, it petered out by 1948, and was abolished completely in 1951. It must be said that one of the selling points of CDU/CSU coalition was exactly "quick and fair" denazification. They did not push for complete abolishment of it, but wanted to end it quickly which matched wishes of general public.

Overall, [first government of Konrad Adenauer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konrad_Adenauer#First_government) (1949-1953) is considered as a huge success, not only economically but also politically. Adenauer among other things managed to secure rearmament of Germany, and US/British support for [Himmerod memorandum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himmerod_memorandum), which "cleared the honor" of German professional soldiers (officers) and commuted sentences of those sentenced for war crimes by Western Allies. West Germany became part of anti-communist block in Europe, and by 1953 elections large part of immediate (WW2) past was put behind. Ordinary German citizens were now secure that no one would ask much question what did they do during the war, but also that German state would recognize their diplomas, pension rights and other benefits and privileges earned during the period of Third Reich. With this "clean slate" situation, many former NSDAP members, no longer under denazification restrictions, openly participated in political life and were elected on various lists. Note that they did not have unified political program, i.e. they belonged both to the left and right of political spectrum. As a rule, those most successful among them skillfully differentiated themselves from National-Socialist ideology and adapted to new circumstances.

Comment: This answer doesn't look as if it was written in the year 2021: ', or is now in Soviet Union and satellites'. Please clarify if this is your text, otherwise name the source that it came from.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Answer was written from the 1953 perspective, since that was OP question. Therefore, in the "now" USSR was at the peek of its power.